# How to sort JSON array on click?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, json, sorting

I'm trying to do a button which sorts JSON array by name and by year. I did this and it sorts results correctly by year but I'm willing to change order on click. Also I'd like to have option to sort results by name.

```
const showResults = movies
.sort((a, b) => (a.Year < b.Year ? -1 : 1))
.map((movie, idx) => {
return (
  <div key={idx}>
    <div>
      <h4>{movie.Year}</h4>
      <h3>{movie.Title}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
)
```

I also tried this and then call it inside on click:

```
const sortResults = movies.sort((a, b) => (a.Year < b.Year ? 1 : -1));

<button onClick={sortResults}>Sort results</button>
```

**EDIT:**

Found this solution. It works partly but it's not exactly what I'm looking for.

First I did new state hook:

```
const [sortResults, setSortResults] = useState('');
```

Handler for select dropdown:

```
const sortHandler = (e) => {
  setSortResults(e.target.value);
}
```

Then I wrote new sort method inside `showResults`. First two sorting movies by year and last two by title:

```
const showResults = movies
.sort((a, b) => {
  if (sortResults === 'newest') {
    return (a.Year > b.Year) ? -1 : 1;
  }
  if (sortResults === 'oldest') {
    return (a.Year > b.Year) ? 1 : -1;
  }
  if (sortResults === 'az') {
    return (a.Title > b.Title);
  }
  if (sortResults === 'za') {
    return (a.Title < b.Title);
  }
  return 0;
}

...

)
```

Then I created `select` dropdown for both sorting options:

```
<select onChange={sortHandler} defaultValue='none'>
  <option disabled value='none'>Sort</option>
  <option value='oldest'>Oldest</option>
  <option value='newest'>Newest</option>
</select>

<select onChange={sortHandler} defaultValue='none'>
  <option disabled value='none'>Sort</option>
  <option value='az'>A-Z</option>
  <option value='za'>Z-A</option>
</select>
```

I want to swap those `select` dropdowns to buttons and change order by clicking same button. Example: I click Year button, order changes to Newest -> Oldest, I click button again order changes back to Oldest -> Newest. How to do that?

**EDIT2:**

I tried to modify `sortHandler` this way. When I click the button first time value changes to `'old'` but after that value doesn't change anymore..

```
const sortHandler = (e) => {
  setSortResults(e.target.value);
  if (e.target.value === '') {
    setSortResults('old');
  }
  else if (e.target.value === 'old') {
    setSortResults('new');
  }
}
```

Here's the code for button:

```
<button value='' onClick={sortHandler}>
  Sort
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: it seems that the trouble you are having is related to the sorting of the data not displaying the data with React to the solution below only implements the sorting functionality. Also without knowing the React code that comes previously I do not know how the data was defined so I assumed a simple variable, if you are using the `useState` hook you will need to update the values in accordance with your `useState` function.

Below is the solution, `onclick` needs to be set to a function not a variable. This solution calls `sortOnClick()` when the button is clicked. `sortOnClick()` then determines if we are sorting by the title or not, this value could be set anyway that you would like i.e. a dropdown in the html, and then uses one of the reusable sort functions that was defined. The function the logs the value of movies into the console.

javascript index.js

```
let movies = [
    {
        year : 1998,
        title : 'A movie'
    },
    {
        year : 2011,
        title : 'Captian America'
    },
    {
        year : 2005,
        title : 'Toy Story 2'
    },
    {
        year : 2006,
        title : 'B movie'
    }
]

function sortByTitle(a, b){
    var uppercase_a = a.title.toUpperCase();
    var uppercase_b = b.title.toUpperCase();
    return (uppercase_a > uppercase_b)? 1 : -1
}

function sortByYear(a,b){
    return (a.year > b.year)? 1: -1
}

function sortOnClick(){
    let title = true;
    
    if(title){
        movies = movies.sort((a,b) => sortByTitle(a,b))
    }
    else{
        movies = movies.sort((a,b) => sortByYear(a,b))
    }
    console.log(movies)
}
```

html index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    <button onclick="sortOnClick()">Sort</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You have two issues, one is that you are not reactively  rendering you movie data. You are creating you html once which does not rerun when `setMovie` is called so you do not see the ui update when the array is changed. The second is you need to create a sort function for each and call it within the onClick of the button.

Comment: I just can't figure out the issue. I updated to original post what I tried..